# How to get data from related table in Laravel (one to many)?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have two tables: `users`, `orders`. I try to get all orders for current user.

```
Users    Orders
_____    ______
id | name  id | user_id
```

**User model:**

```
public function orders(){
     return $this->hasMany("App\Order");
}
```

**Order model:**

```
public function user(){
    return $this->hasOne("App\User", 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

**Query in controller:**

```
public function index()
{

    $orders = Order::where('user_id', Auth::guard('api')->id())->get();
    return response()->json(
        $orders->user
    );
}
```

I get NULL result, I do something wrong, because there are related rows in both tables.

Comment: The controller function won't work because `get()` method returns a collection and you're trying to get a property `user` of a collection which doesn't make sense. What's that function supposed to do?

Comment: So, I need to get all information about user from table `Users` and get in same request all orders of user. What instead `get()` I should use?

Comment: What about using `Auth::user()->id` instead of `Auth::guard('api')->id()` ? I get null using what you have.

Comment: Problem is not in this, I think. This is trivial issue

Comment: Seems works this: `public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }` But I can not see result about user in `dd($c = Order::all());` I just nee d to use $c in look and get here `$key->user->name`

Comment: Back to my previous comment, any time I `dd(Auth::guard('api')->id());`, I get `null` returned. If you need the user data as well, try `User::with('orders')`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to retrieve all the Orders belonging to the current user, try using the following function.

```
public function index()
{
    $orders = Auth::user()->with('Orders')->get()->toArray();//To get the output in array
    /*        ^               ^
     This will get the user | This will get all the Orders related to the user*/
     
    return response()->json($orders);
}
```

As pointed out by @Martin Heralecký, you would also need to change the `hasOne()` to `belongsTo()` in Order Model. See following (copied from @Martin Heralecký answer)

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo("App\User");// second and third arguments are unnecessary.
}
```

## Why belongsTo():

`has_one` and `belongs_to` generally are the same in the sense that they point to the other related model. `belongs_to` make sure that this model has the foreign_key defined.  `has_one` makes sure that the other model has_foreign key defined.

Your `$orders` array will look something like this:

```
User => [
 id => 'user id',
 name => 'user name'
 orders => [
  0 => [
         //order data
       ]
  1 => [
         //order data
       ]
       .
       .
       .
       .
   ]
]
```

Answer (score 2):

In Order model you need to use the `belongsTo` relationship:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo("App\User"); // second and third arguments are unnecessary.
}
```

Comment: It returns `Null` again, without fields from table `User`

Answer (score 2):

In User model you can use hasMany relationship, for example in:

`App/User.php`

Add

```
public function orders()
{
   return $this->hasMany("App\Order", "user_id", "id");
}
```

Now you can use this:

```
return User::find(1)->orders;
```

Comment: Can I get all in one result?

Answer (score -1):

make sure all data is filled in, no data taken from that relation is null, just one data from the relation list contains null it will create an error stating that the variable is null.

model:

```
public function arviQrs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ArviQr::class);
    }

public function merchant()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Merchant::class);
    }
```

controller:

```
$qrs = ArviQr::orderBy('create_time','desc')->get();
```

blade:

```
@foreach ($qrs as $key => $item)
$item->merchant->name
@endforeach
```

in my database i have one data arviQrs.merchant_id is null, and then i change it to true id and voalaa its not error and running.

its error bcs arviQrs.merchant_id and merchant.id is angker, cannot be null

Comment: Not an appropriate answer, as the question is regarding JSON results rather than regular blade view.